# How to exclude the untargeted pixel from classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, classification

I am trying to perform a crop-type classification in a complex area where my region of interest (ROI) contains multiple crops, but I am only interested in detecting two or three specific crops. My current code is classifying the entire ROI, including the areas with other crops that I am not interested in. How can I modify my code to classify only the pixels containing the specific crops I am interested in and leave the other pixels unclassified?" https://code.earthengine.google.com/d26d80e465b860f296e9a5e667f3b184

```
////////////////////TrainingData//////////// 
var referenceData = ee.Image().byte() .paint(Rice, 0) .paint(Maize, 1) .paint(cotton,2) .rename("class");

var training = stacked.float().addBands(referenceData).stratifiedSample({ numPoints: 0, classBand: "class", region: Delta, scale: 30, projection: stacked.select(0).projection(), classValues: [0,1,2], classPoints: [1000,1000,1000] })

// //How balanced are the training data? // //print(training.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), ["class"])); Map.addLayer(training,{},'training_sample',false);

// Filter out the null property values and try again.

var sample=training.randomColumn(); var split=0.7 var training_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',split)); var validation_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',split));

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({ numberOfTrees: 128, minLeafPopulation: 4 }) .train({ features: training_sample, classProperty: 'class', inputProperties: stacked.bandNames(),//bands// })

var classified = stacked.classify(classifier, 'Classified');

Map.addLayer(classified.randomVisualizer(),{},'classification', false);

// Classify the validation data. var validated = validation_sample.classify(classifier);

var testAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix('class', 'classification'); print('Test overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy()); print('Test kappa accuracy: ', testAccuracy.kappa()); print('Training producer accuracy: ', testAccuracy.producersAccuracy());
```

Answer (score 0):

if the unwanted crop areas are not part of your sampling area, no worries, just do the classification of every pixel including your unwanted crops and then clip by shapefile later.